# Query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Tags: java, jpa

Tenho um cenário com as seguintes entidades:`Treinamento`, `Curso` e `Aulas`.
Um `Treinamento` tem um relacionamento `ManyToOne` para `Curso`.
E `Aula` tem um relacionamento `ManyToOne` para um `Curso`.

Quero realizar uma consulta que dado um determinado id de treinamento me retorne o treinamento com o seu curso e com suas respectivas aulas preenchidas no objeto. Estou fazendo a consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
Treinamento retorno = null;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT t FROM Treinamento t ");
    sb.append("INNER JOIN t.idCurso c ");
    sb.append("LEFT JOIN FETCH c.aulas a ");
    sb.append("WHERE t = '"+String.valueOf(treinamento)+"' ");

    retorno = (Treinamento)this.em.createQuery(sb.toString()).getSingleResult();
```

E estou recebendo o erro:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=a,role=br.com.empresa.domain.ptreinamentos.Curso.aulas,tableName=Aula,tableAlias=aulas2_,origin=Curso curso1_,columns={curso1_.id ,className=br.com.empresa.domain.ptreinamentos.Aula}}]
```

O erro me diz que o dono do relacionamento fetch não está na clausula select. Neste caso o dono do relacionamento seria o `Curso`. Qual seria a forma correta de se realizar esta consulta ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solução para este problema é que ao realizar um JOIN FETCH deve-se começar a fazer o FETCH desde o primeiro relacionamento, no meu caso a consulta ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
Treinamento retorno = null;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT t FROM Treinamento t ");
sb.append("INNER JOIN FETCH t.idCurso c ");
sb.append("LEFT JOIN FETCH c.aulas a ");
sb.append("WHERE t = '"+String.valueOf(treinamento)+"' ");

retorno = (Treinamento)this.em.createQuery(sb.toString()).getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score -3):

Essa situação é bem parecida com um caso de `count` numa `query` paginada. A resposta correta a esse tipo de situação, se encontra em declarar a consulta de `count` sem os `FETCHs` e adicioná-los afim de evitar o problema de N+1 somente na query de busca do objeto. Segue resposta em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583594/10746857.